# Other ways to add element in an array?

Tags: php, syntax

```
$a = ['foo' => 'bar'];
```

If I want to add new elements in this array I would usually write this

```
$a['foo2'] = 'bar2';
$a['foo3'] = 'bar3';
$a['foo4'] = 'bar4';
```

Is there some other syntax so I can add elements like this without overwriting `$a`?

```
$a =    [   'foo2' => 'bar2',
            'foo3' => 'bar3',
            'foo4' => 'bar4'];
```

Comment: Take a look at `array_merge()`

Comment: You could start by reading the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: After your curious question i am more curious about what made you to find another METHOD to add array element ?

Comment: @akashraigade finding a shorter way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do something like this:

```
$arr1 = array('foo2' => 'bar2');
$arr2 = array('foo3' => 'bar3');
$arr3 = $arr1 + $arr2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_merge` to add an array to the end of another array.

```
$a = array_merge($a, $b);
```

where `$b` is:

```
$b =    [   'foo2' => 'bar2',
            'foo3' => 'bar3',
            'foo4' => 'bar4'];
```

Comment: This is a good answer but @Pritam Banerjee posted something new to me. Still thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Or just do:

```
$a = ['foo' => 'bar'];
$a = array_merge([$a,'foo2' => 'bar2',
            'foo3' => 'bar3',
            'foo4' => 'bar4'];
```

Will return what you want.

Answer (score -2):

How about this ?
I think it is simplest to add element into an array

```
<?php
 $cart = [];
//to add one
 array_push($cart, 13); 
 // to add multiple
 array_push($cart, 13,14,15); 

?>
```

Comment: This will push an array into the array so you end up with Array
(
    [foo] => bar
    [0] => Array
        (
            [foo2] => bar2
            [foo3] => bar3
            [foo4] => bar4
        )

)

Comment: @akashraigade Please don't downvote (or threaten to downvote) people who flag your content. That's revenge downvoting and it is not allowed here.

Comment: I was joking mate , i am a responsible  member of stackoverflow . I never votedown even questions are wronge and even have answer some vitedowned questions have helped people to make their negatively  marked questions improve :Have peace brother

Answer (score -2):

> You could create a simple Function for that like so:

```
<?php

    /**
     * @param $mainArray => THE ARRAY TO WHICH OTHER ELEMENTS (INCL. ARRAYS/OBJECTS) SHOULD BE ADDED
     * @param $data      => A KEY-VALUE PAIR ARRAY OR A NORMAL STRING/NUMBER
     * @return array
     */
    function arrayAdd(&$mainArray, $data){
        if(is_array($data)){
            foreach($data as $k=>$v){
                $mainArray[$k]  = $v;
            }
        }else if(is_string($data)){
            $mainArray[]        = $data;
        }
        return $mainArray;
    }

    // CREATE A OBJECT (TO SHOW IT COULD ALSO HANDLE THAT AS WELL)
    $obj    = new stdClass();
    $obj->name  = 'Some Name';
    $obj->tel   = '+1 202 532 00 00 00';

    // THE MAIN ARRAY TO WHICH OTHER ELEMENTS SHOULD BE ADDED 
    $main   = ['foo1' => 'bar1', 'foo2' => 'bar2'];

    // A COLLECTION OF DATA TO ADD TO $main
    $data   = [
        'one'   => 'Un',
        'two'   => 'Deux',
        'three' => 'Trois',
        'four'  => 'Quart',
        'obj'   => $obj,
    ];

    // CALL THE FUNCTION AND PASS THE PARAMETERS
    var_dump( arrayAdd($main, $data) );

    // YIELDS:: 
    array (size=7)
      'foo1' => string 'bar1' (length=4)
      'foo2' => string 'bar2' (length=4)
      'one' => string 'Un' (length=2)
      'two' => string 'Deux' (length=4)
      'three' => string 'Trois' (length=5)
      'four' => string 'Quart' (length=5)
      'obj' => 
        object(stdClass)[1]
          public 'name' => string 'Some Name' (length=9)
          public 'tel' => string '+1 202 532 00 00 00' (length=19)
```

Comment: This is array_merge with eyes closed, walking backwards. Why?